# Validation framework for spring MVC app

Tags: spring, validation, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I would like to get some best approaches for implementing validation framework for a Spring Web App. My goal is to reduce script validation , at the same time implementing real time validation. I cant use the JSR303 or Spring MVC validation because of the data models definition constraints. How does rule engine work with Web App? Are there any other validation frameworks which can fit on Spring App?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [general Spring validation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validator) by implementing [Spring's Validator](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/validation/Validator.html).

Read this other Stack Overflow post for more information : [Spring MVC: How to perform validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146298/spring-mvc-how-to-perform-validation/12149331#12149331)

Comment: Thanks. But I am looking for a library where the validation can be used both by Client and server. Here is one i came over,   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661322/rule-engine-in-javascript